# how to assign the variable to the argument in execute process task?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

i tried to pass the variable in argument (execute process task) .
i read msdn article in that they told to pass like @variablename in argument.

i tried @variablename,@[User::variablename] but couldn't achieve.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link !! I found answer .

http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-unzip-zip-files-in-ssis-how.html